# Can I undo the upgrade to iOS 7 by restoring to iOS 6.1.3?

Tags: iphone, ios

I recently attempted to follow [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPyQxSozAwM) to upgrade my device (iPhone 4) to iOS 7 without being a developer or registering a UDID.

I loaded and installed iOS 7 and got to the configuration screen. However efter attempting to go through the configuration process it says:

> We’re unable to complete your activation. This device is not
>   registered as part of the iPhone Developer Program. If you are a
>   member of the Program, please register your device in the iPhone
>   Developer Program Portal.

The problem is this is also what it says on iTunes so there is no way to access it from the computer.

How can I downgrade back to 6.1.3? I suppose I could register as a paid developer for iOS 7, but that involves forking over $99 and I'm not even sure I could revert to iOS 6 even then.

Additional Information:

- I started with an unjailbroken iOS 6.1.3.
- I downloaded iOS 7.0 CDMA for iPhone 4 from [here](http://imzdl.com/ios.php)
- I have Verizon
- I Have the iOS 6.1.3 version for my iPhone downloaded from [here](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/), but I am unsure how I can restore from it because iTunes will not let me do anything because of the above mentioned message.

Update: I managed to entere recovery mode by pressing "power" for 3 seconds, "home" and power for 10 seconds, and just "home" until it had entered recovery mode. I have then begun to restore the phone which requires iOS 6.1.3 to download again through iTunes. Note that the first time you restore it may not work. Mine still booted to iOS 7 until I tried again.

Comment: Try this:
http://www.imore.com/how-downgrade-ios-7-beta-back-ios-6 (I can't comment due to my low rep)

Comment: I'm going to close this since there was a temporary window between WWDC and September 22 where Apple was signing both iOS 7 and iOS 6 software. The answers here no longer apply, but are useful for historical reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is likely the baseband was updated along with the OS, but if you have a good backup of the phone, I might try restoring it in recovery mode.

1. Power off the iPhone
2. Plug in the iPhone to your computer via USB.
3. Press and hold the "power" button with one hand for 3 seconds
4. Hold down the "home" button as well for ten more seconds
5. Release "power" button but continue to hold "home" button until device enters recovery mode.

I don't have a device to test this and it might not work. You might have to get a jailbreak tool to modify the OS and/or firmware of the device and then restore 6.1.3 on it.

Comment: Why are we answering these now? Clearly the user pirated a copy of iOS. Additionally, anything to do with the unreleased OS is under NDA. Why are these not being closed?

Comment: @cksum we can discuss why in depth on [meta], but this question is more about how to undo a jailbreak or unauthorized OS than it is about how iOS 7 works. This is a hardware question at its root about how shipping hardware works.

Comment: Reread his question. He is asking how to go back from an unauthorized iOS 7 install to the most recent jailbroken iOS 6 (6.1.3). There's nothing that pertains to undoing a jailbreak. The question also contains admission to obtaining the beta from a known pirate website and goes as far as to link to it. I would think it would be professional pride to respect Apple in cases like these.

Answer (score 4):

Once you upgrade to iOS7 from iOS6, you will not be able to downgrade from iOS7 back to iOS6. You **can** downgrade the beta, but not the production release.

Caveat: According to [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5326157?tstart=0), as long as Apple is still [signing](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/SHSH) iOS6 releases, you can downgrade. Once the signing stops, the downgrades will also.

EDIT: According to [iMore](http://www.imore.com/psa-you-can-no-longer-downgrade-ios-7-back-ios-6), as of today, you can no longer downgrade.

Comment: In the sense that downgrades do not move content from iOS 7 back to iOS 6 I suppose you are correct, but I've downgraded an iPhone 4 yesterday from the production OS.

Comment: See the caveat above.

Comment: You are totally correct about the signing window - very good edit.

Comment: I also just downgraded iOS 7 (the official release) to iOS 6 and it worked perfectly, so they must still be signing it. Luckily I did it in time!

Answer (score 0):

[Copied as an answer here since this question "[Will it be possible to downgrade from iOS7(Final) to iOS 6.1.3?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102387/will-it-be-possible-to-downgrade-from-ios7final-to-ios-6-1-3/)" was marked as duplicate and bmike suggested that it be moved here to provide additional information]

You can downgrade by following the steps [here](http://readwrite.com/2013/06/13/how-to-downgrade-from-ios-7-beta-back-to-ios-6) (it's for iOS 7 beta, but will work for the release version too).

Keep in mind that Apple usually stops signing the older version of iOS shortly after the release of a new version. Until the time Apple continues signing iOS 6, you will be able to downgrade the OS. Nobody can predict when Apple would stop signing iOS 6.

Once Apple stops signing iOS 6, it wouldn't be possible to downgrade (unless you look or wait for jailbreaks, hacks and such solutions, which would depend on the iPhone model you have).