# Downgrade from iOS7(Final) to iOS 6.1.3?

Tags: ios

Will it be possible to downgrade from iOS 7.0.1 to iOS 6 ? Just in case if i wanted iOS6 back.I'm asking about iOS7 final public version not the beta build.

Comment: iOS 7.0.1 doesn't work on any shipping product (and is currently only released for 5c and 5s). I'm going to close this as duplicate as it's not really covering new ground as written. Feel free to edit in details that make it different than the previous questions and we can look at reopening this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can downgrade by following the steps [here](http://readwrite.com/2013/06/13/how-to-downgrade-from-ios-7-beta-back-to-ios-6) (it's for iOS 7 beta, but will work for the release version too).

Keep in mind that Apple usually stops signing the older version of iOS shortly after the release of a new version. Until the time Apple continues signing iOS 6, you will be able to downgrade the OS. Nobody can predict when Apple would stop signing iOS 6.

Once Apple stops signing iOS 6, it wouldn't be possible to downgrade (unless you look or wait for jailbreaks, hacks and such solutions, which would depend on the iPhone model you have).

Comment: Let's get your answer over here in case this stays closed. The linked article and extra information is quite good. -> http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93809/can-i-undo-the-upgrade-to-ios-7-by-restoring-to-ios-6-1-3