# iPhone 4S I did upgrade and hate it, want to go back

Tags: iphone

If I can't go back I'm getting rid of iPhone for droid, any help would be appreciated. My iPhone and all upgrades are legal, just hate new upgrade...
Please help me
Terry

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to tell you that there is no official way to downgrade from iOS7 to iOS6 anymore as Apple stopped signing the 6.1.4/6.1.3 firmware. Every time a software-upgrade is done iTunes asks for a verification of the firmware. As of 21st of September Apple stopped signed the 6.1.3/6.1.4 firmware and therefore iTunes will refuse a downgrade to iO6. For more information see the following [blog](http://blog.ih8sn0w.com/2013/09/some-updates.html) for more information.

update: this question has already been answered over here: [Can I undo the upgrade to iOS 7 by restoring to iOS 6.1.3?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93809/can-i-undo-the-upgrade-to-ios-7-by-restoring-to-ios-6-1-3)